# Rails substitute scaffold User for rails g devise user

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I've got a running app (where I created Users through a scaffold) and only now stumble upon the "devise" gem. Now I'd like to include this in my app and manage Users through it. I was thinking that I could maybe drop the db,

```
rails generate devise User
```

and substitute model, views, and any other entries that still remain from the Users scaffold before destroying the scaffold all together.

Since this feels pretty error-prone, I'm looking for an easier way to handle this. The thing is that I don't want to rebuild the whole application even though obviously a lot of things rely on the User...

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to create User Model, devise will create it with columns.

So drop User table first and then run following command:

```
rails generate devise User
```

Comment: Yeah I know that devise will create it. My question is whether this will affect any of my other models. E.g. I've got a model that includes "belongs_to :user", while the inital User model "has_many XYZ" - will I be able to substitute the inital User model through the devise User or will this affect the whole application?

Comment: No it will not affect to other models. Devise will create model User.rb so add has_many XYZ in that file.